# Worksheet_change macro running multiple times in excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I have couple worksheets where I am using a macro to do some calculations. This calculation is supposed to run if any cell in the range is changed.

Below is the code that runs.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' Check if change is made to the correct range of cells.
   Dim Results As Variant

   'Defaults while sheet only used in Rotterdam
   mGravityUnit = UnitDensity
   mVolumeUnit = UnitCubicMetres
   mTempUnit = UnitCelcius

    With Application
        If Not (.Intersect(Target, Range("Grade1ROBTemp")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade1ROBDensity")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade1ROBVCF")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade2ROBTemp")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade2ROBDensity")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade2ROBVCF")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade3ROBTemp")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade3ROBDensity")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("Grade3ROBVCF")) Is Nothing) Then
            ' Change in Volume Temp or Density
            Dim ThisRow As Integer, VCF As Double
            ThisRow = Target.Row
            If Not (Cells(ThisRow, 8) = "" Or Cells(ThisRow, 9) = "") Then
                WaitFor (0.05)
                Results = VCF_Calculation(Cells(ThisRow, 8), mTempUnit, Cells(ThisRow, 9), mGravityUnit, mVolumeUnit)
                Cells(ThisRow, 10) = Results
            Else
                Cells(ThisRow, 10) = ""
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This code works fine in one worksheet, running only for the rows that have changes.

But in the other sheet, this same code runs for all the rows in the range, instead of the one row where the cell was changed. Because of this, macro fails to run properly, as it is taking more time than required to work.

Clearly, I am supposed to set some property in excel range that will cause the macro to run only for the updated row, and not for all the rows.

Edit:
I guess I defined ranges wrong, that's why it was triggering the change event again and again.

Disabling events fixed the problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Start by adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` just after intersect then `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting the sub. Failing to add this crucial code will have the sub try to run on top of itself as soon as you change a value on the worksheet.

Comment: Let me try this. Give me a moment.

Comment: I agree with @Jeeped.  This code `Cells(ThisRow, 10) = xxx` will re-trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Although, I wonder why this works fine in the other sheet. Maybe, I have defined the ranges wrong. Anyway, I added the code  in all the sheets to make sure it does not give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` just after intersect then `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting the sub. Failing to add this crucial code will have the sub try to run on top of itself as soon as you change a value on the worksheet.

Use the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) to stitch all of your named ranges together.

Don't even dim vars before you know you are going to need them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'only process if we are dealing with a single Target
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("Grade1ROBTemp"), Range("Grade1ROBDensity"), _
      Range("Grade1ROBVCF"), Range("Grade2ROBTemp"), Range("Grade2ROBDensity"), Range("Grade2ROBVCF"), _
      Range("Grade3ROBTemp"), Range("Grade3ROBDensity"), Range("Grade3ROBVCF"))) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Defaults while sheet only used in Rotterdam
        mGravityUnit = UnitDensity
        mVolumeUnit = UnitCubicMetres
        mTempUnit = UnitCelcius

        ' Change in Volume Temp or Density
        Dim ThisRow As Long, VCF As Double, Results As Variant
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If CBool(Len(Cells(ThisRow, 8))) And CBool(Len(Cells(ThisRow, 9))) Then
            WaitFor (0.05)
            Results = VCF_Calculation(Cells(ThisRow, 8), mTempUnit, Cells(ThisRow, 9), mGravityUnit, mVolumeUnit)
            Cells(ThisRow, 10) = Results
        Else
            Cells(ThisRow, 10) = ""
        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Only process your code if a single call is the Target. If more than a single cell has changed then the above code won't work. You will have to use something  like `For Each rng in INtersect(...`.

Comment: Thanks. This works faster than the existing code. And sorry, it wasn't my code. I simply copied the code from an existing sheet, only in my case it threw this error.